# filtering "custom post types" by "custom post fields" using filters and "pre get posts"

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type, custom-fields

I created a custom post time with the name of 'apartment'.

i use the archive-apartment.php file to loop and show the posts in a grid format.
For the loop i use the "pre_get_posts" action.

this is my "pre_get_posts" action on my fuctions.php

```
function post_query($query){
    if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()){
        if(is_category()){
            $query->set('post_type', array( 'post', 'apartment' ) );
            $query -> set('posts_per_page', 3);
        }

        if( is_post_type_archive( 'apartment' )){


            $query -> set('posts_per_page', 8);
        }
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'post_query');
```

and this is my category.php code

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
     <div class="container">
     <?php
  $counter = 1; //start counter

  $grids = 3; //Grids per row


       if(have_posts()) : 
          while( have_posts()) : the_post();

  ?>
  <?php
  //Show the left hand side column
  if($counter == 1) :
  ?>
  <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-4">
             <div class="center">
              <div class="postimage">
                 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_custom_logo(); ?></a>
              </div>
                  <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                  <h4><?php the_category(' '); ?></h4>
                  <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Price', true); ?>
           </div>
           </div>
  <?php

  elseif($counter == 2) :
  ?>
  <div class="col-md-4 border2">
     <div class="center">
              <div class="postimage">
                 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_custom_logo(); ?></a>
              </div>
                  <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                  <h4><?php the_category(' '); ?></h4>
                  <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Price', true); ?>
           </div>
           </div>

  <?php
  elseif($counter == $grids) :
  ?>
  <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="center">
              <div class="postimage">
                 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_custom_logo(); ?></a>
              </div>
                  <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                  <h4><?php the_category(' '); ?></h4>
                  <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Price', true); ?>
           </div>
           </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <?php
  $counter = 0;
  endif;
  ?>

  <?php
  $counter++;
 endwhile;

  ?>

              <div class="row">

                  <div class="col-xs-12 text-left ">
                     <?php next_posts_link('<< Older post'); ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-12 text-right ">
                     <?php previous_posts_link('Newer post >>'); ?>
                  </div>

              </div>



  <?php
  endif;


  ?>

  </div>

  <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Now i want to add filters so users can sort the posts in the custom-post-type "apartment" by two custom fields : "Price" and "number of rooms"
i created a form and specified the method=get

```
<form action="http://localhost/wordpress4/apartment" method="get">

            <label>Price:</label>
            <select name="Price">
                <option value="">Any</option>
                <option value="22000">22000</option>
                <option value="23000">23000</option>
                <option value="24000">24000</option>
                <option value="25000">25000</option>                
            </select>

            <label>Rooms:</label>
            <select name="Price">
                <option value="">Any</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>                         
            </select>

            <button type="submit" name="">search</button>
        </form>
```

and then i used this code bellow to catch the GET values and store it in two variables that i will use in the loop through the pre_get_posts filter:

```
<?php 

       if($_GET['Price'] && !empty($_GET['Price']))
        {
            $price = $_GET['Price'];
        }
        if($_GET['Rooms'] && !empty($_GET['Rooms']))
        {
            $rooms = $_GET['Rooms'];
        }

 ?>
```

Now i want to know how can i change the fuction post_query($query) -"this is the fuction im using with the pre_get_posts"- so users can filter the posts when they are on the custom post type url : localhost/wordpress4/apartment/.

Also I want users to see all the posts before they start using the filters (i mean when they visit the page for the first time ).

Thank you